# ASP.NET Identity 2: Password Reset Token will not pass correctly

Tags: asp.net-identity

When I attempt to follow the many examples provided I run into a couple of problems. The latest iteration of the code looks like this;

```
string passwordResetToken = await _applicationUserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(u.Id);
string code = callbackUrl + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(passwordResetToken);
await _applicationUserManager.SendEmailAsync(u.Id, RESET_SUBJECT, string.Format(RESET_BODY, u.FirstName, u.LastName, code));
```

The password reset link looks like:

> http://localhost:52819/account/reset/Jn4X1sn4Ybmh9vPJmHO8U7ZdiQqr%2bRJTtn9PAMbtToILxhlUe5by0FwbX0GIY1%2bZuaHX0tAsNtcr52y1kFYPZabGwFE%2ftWvfvttKH1trLkbekhxwAZm0UbrAyZHtZyx1q3HbjFwB5lxEvfpzlvdFx9%2bByE5Nr3eehpyvyeqshhiKkr1xvPb4Oc%2bStjDFBj2qX4Qwe7dHayx8n27GaiRdNA%3d%3d

- Problem 1: If I just try to use the password reset token 'as is' I get a routing error because of the '+' sign (this appearently creates a 'double escape sequences' which is not allow by default in IIS...for what looks like good reason.)
- Problem 2:If I URLEncode(passwordResetToken) the result "code" looks good, but when I drop that into an email and click on the link it gets URLdecoded and the same error occurs...
- Problem 3: Even when I enable double escapes (in web.config) the resulting URL gets parsed in such a way that it won't get routed back to the account controller correctly.

I'm not finding anybody else complaining about this, so I figure I have missed something foolish...but I can not find it..

Comment: Instead of `account/reset/Jn4X1....` does `account/reset?token=Jn4X1....` work without `UrlEncode()`?

Comment: Good idea, but unfortunately, no... tried it with and without urlEncode and got nowhere.

Comment: correction: after realizing I had slightly mangled the syntax for the RouteConfig using ...?id=.... worked, only with the UrlEncode (slashes appear to be the source of the problem.)

Comment: @Jasen, if you want to transform your comment to an answer I would be pleased to give you proper credit.

Comment: You're not alone. I just tried refactoring the token into the URL rather than the query string. Slashes are indeed the source of the problem. Sticking with query strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of defining a custom route with uri parameters you could try just a regular query string parameter.

```
var url = "account/reset?token=" + HttpUtilityUrlEncode(token);
```